# Openfire sends empty (without stamp attr) jabber:x:delay extension to smack

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack

I receive offline message from openfire server, but it contains empty jabber:x:delay extension.

The message I receive is:

```
<message id="qU7N8-64" to="ac1@server.jj.ru" from="ac2@server.jj.ru/4847791" type="chat">
      <body>test message</body>
      <delay xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay"></delay>
      <x xmlns="jabber:x:delay"></x>
</message>
```

This message I receive with smack library.

But when I connect to openfire with Miranda IM, openfire sends extension jabber:x:delay with data.

Why openfire sends empty jabber:x:delay only to smack library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line after connection.

```
ProviderManager.getInstance()addExtensionProvider("x","jabber:x:delay", new DelayInformationProvider());
```

Answer (score 1):

Openfire doesn't do anything different since it doesn't know (or care) what client is connected.  The packet you are showing is very peculiar, since it contains both the legacy and current versions of Delayed Delivery, but with missing required attributes in both.

Try running with VM argument **-Dsmack.debugEnabled=true** set.  Then check the incoming **raw** packets for the actual message content.  There is most likely one of 2 things happening.

1. The time is missing, so Miranda is compensating by populating it with some default value, like current date.
2. The time format is not according to spec, so the parser in Smack is omitting it.

Comment: Smack not parse stamp attribute in message.